# Docker compose on Windows: no such file or directory

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run two services with docker compose: a MySQL server and a SAMP server.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    volumes:
     - ./mysql:/var/nw-mysql-data
    env_file:
      - .env

  samp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ./samp03svr
    ports:
      - "7777:7777"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./samp03svr /app/
```

The problem is in the command of the `samp` service. It throws the following exception when I run `docker-compose up`:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

The weird thing, is that if I change the samp's command for an `ls` like this:

```
command: ls
```

I can see the binary file that I'm trying to execute listed, and docker is saying that there's no such file...
Help?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the `ls` command return, ran from the `command` instruction of the `samp` service:

[image]

Comment: The "no such file or directory" error could be caused by a wrong-architecture binary (are you on an ARM Mac?) or missing shared libraries or a missing script interpreter.   Where did the `samp03svr` binary come from?

Comment: It's a PC running Windows 10. Binary file came from here https://www.sa-mp.com/download.php . Linux server option, since my samp service is running an ubuntu:20.04.